# Using Apache Flume Kafka sink on Cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I want to use the Kafka sink that comes with Apache Flume. However, it seems that the cygnus-common package is based on Apache Flume 1.4 whereas the Kafka sink was added around Apache Flume 1.7. If I add the Kafka jar file to the cygnus-common library it fails because the the cygnus-common core is outdated.

So it is possible to use the latest flume version (1.8) instead of cygnus-common with cygnus-ngsi libraries? In that case I can switch between using Apache Flume Kafka sink and the NGSIKafkaSink?

Answer (score 1):

I am Andrés from UPM Fiware Team. You are right pointing out that Fiware Cygnus is based on Apache Flume 1.4 so, Answering your question, exist a high probability that the sinks used in a posterior version of Flume don't be compatible with Cygnus. We are working on an update of Cygnus in order to use the lastest release of flume and also manage the NGSIV2 notifications in a native way but it is a work in progress and takes time. I think that currently the only way to work with Cygnus and kafka sink is using the GE provided by FIWARE in his corresponding versions.

I